# Ag-Grid ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Im using angular 11.1.0
with ag-grid 24.0.0

When I try to load a dynamic angular component with the frameworkComponent @Input I get this following error: **ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.**

**This is how I declare it in the HTML:**

> <ag-grid-angular
> style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"
> class="ag-theme-alpine"
> [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
> [rowData]="item.condittions",
> (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
> [columnDefs]="columnDefs">

**And in the component:**

> frameworkComponents: {
> audianceCellRenderer: AssetsCellRendererComponent,   };
>
> columnDefs = [
> {field: 'name'},
> {field: 'sendEmail'},
> {field: 'audiance', cellRendererFramework: 'audianceCellRenderer'},
> {field: 'sop'},   ];

I have tried adding the component to entryComponents, tried adding the component to the withComponnet method of Ag-grid but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please, provide code where you load the component

Comment: can you please provide some code examples of how you are using @Input with frameworkComponent

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes up with this issue,
My mistake was this line:

> {field: 'audience, cellRendererFramework: 'audianceCellRenderer'},

I accidentally entered the key of the component and not the component itself.

Im sure I'm not going to make this mistake again :)

Comment: Yes in may case too.. The issue was in the class which was passing to cellRendererFramework